# javascript / jquery compare datetime values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datetime

Seems to be a simple and commonly asked question but after googling for a while havent come up with an answer.

Very simply, I have two variables each with a datetime value in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

I want to compare which is bigger and perform logic accordingly:

example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r6RMS/)

```
var fromDate = '2014-02-14 07:00';
var toDate = '2014-02-14 07:00';
if (Date.parse(fromDate) > Date.parse(toDate)) {
    alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!")
} else {
    alert("VALID Date Range!\n Start Date is before End");
}
```

The above continuously returns the successful validation.

Any advice, suggestions? examples? Thanks,

Comment: your code is working perfectly. which browser do you use? but the point is both dates you have in your question, not in your example are the same.

Comment: @MehranHatami: If that code works in your browser, that's because your browser exceeds the specification's requirements. You can't rely on it cross-browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: and that's why I asked about the browser.

Comment: @MehranHatami: But "your code is working perfectly" is a bit misleading, if it depends on undocumented browser behavior that's not universal. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It happens that the format you're using can be compared lexigraphically. So no parsing required:

```
var fromDate = '2014-02-14 07:00';
var toDate = '2014-02-14 07:00';
if (fromDate > toDate) {
    alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!");
} else {
    alert("VALID Date Range!\n Start Date is before End");
}
```

This is because the most significant fields precede the less significant fields, throughout the string.

But if you *really* want date/time values, that string format isn't directly supported by the specification. You have three choices:

1. Use a library like MomentJS.
2. Massage the string so that it's in a supported format, but be aware that until ES5, there **was** no standard format dictated by the spec.
3. Do it yourself

The latter looks something like this:

```
function parseMyDate(str) {
    var parts = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/.exec(str);
    if (!parts) {
        return null;
    }
    return new Date(parseInt(parts[1], 10),      // Year
                    parseInt(parts[2], 10) - 1), // Month
                    parseInt(parts[3], 10),      // Day
                    parseInt(parts[4], 10),      // Hours
                    parseInt(parts[5], 10));      // Minutes
}
```

Then use `parseMyDate` where you have `Date.parse` above.

Answer (score 0):

this is real ugly but serves the purpose...

```
    var fromDate = '2014-02-27 09:00';
    fromDate=fromDate.replace("-", "/");
    fromDate=fromDate.replace("-", "/");
    var toDate = '2014-02-27 10:00';
    toDate=toDate.replace("-", "/");
    toDate=toDate.replace("-", "/");


var fromDate=(new Date(fromDate).getTime()/1000);
var toDate=(new Date(toDate).getTime()/1000);

if(fromDate>toDate){
    alert('CORRECT');
} else {
    alert('INCORRECT, from after to');
}
```